# Django on GAE: use_library vs Django-nonrel

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am really new to the world of App Engine development and I want to start with a test project on Django and GAE. I've done some research and found out that there are two major ways to use Django in my app on GAE.

- [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/blog/django) + [djangoappengine](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine)
- [use_library() to load Django from SDK](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django)

Please tell about pros and cons of each way.
Is there anything better than django-nonrel if i will decide to distribute Django code with my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a matter of two different ways to use Django - it's two different versions of Django. App Engine comes bundled with versions 0.96, 1.0 and 1.1 of Django, unmodified from the mainline release. Django-nonrel is a branch of Django, which adds support for App Engine for the database backend.

If you're writing a new app, and you want to use Django for the whole app, including the models, you should use Django-nonrel.

Comment: Django 1.2 as well, as of version 1.4.2 of the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

When using django-nonrel you can use all Django features (including admin, auth, models, queries). I don't have a complete list of django modules which are either not working or partly not working in app engine.
If you use the Django version via `use_library` you have to be careful with app engine's limitations (use their model api, their auth via google accounts and so on).